# I can't get the SearchView or MenuItem from my Fragment class

Tags: android

I am working on this android project like a contact book.

It uses navigation drawer and a search box is included to search a contact. Whenever the user input a character to search box, onquerytextchange() calls a fragment class and replace the content with a customized list view. The list view contains only the minimized info abt the members. When the user clicks on one of the list, the view is replaced again with a view with selected member's full info.

Problem is I want to change the searchview's text with full name of the selected member, if user didn't complete the name but found the one he/she is looking for, and loose the focus from searchview like a real search box but i can't get the SearchView or MenuItem from my Fragment class. I tried using onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu. It returns null value exceptions on calling searchview.setquery() method. pls help me through it